# Reliably resize images in ems?

Tags: css, html, safari

I have 2 instances of images with text that need to resize to the same amount as related text, which have been set in ems. One is a logotype in a navigational menu, as a foreground image and one is a unique headline that have been font-replaced in the old-fashioned way of a background image and negative text-indent.

In Firefox and Chrome at least, setting the proper em size for the height gives the correct behavior. I'm not setting the width to avoid perspective issues.

In Safari, as late as 5.1.7, however, the image is shown too big. Any suggestions or thoughts for steps towards a solution here? I haven't tested IE yet, but I am supplying specific styles for 7, 8 and 9.

**I'd prefer resizing working also when user is zooming text only. The end objective is to have the image resize in the exact same amount as the text does, as the image text sixe matches the real text.**

**HTML5:**

```
ul id="one" class="nav">
    <!--Logotype-->
    <li class="logo"> <a href="/">
      <h1><img src="http://bitly.com/YV6G0S"></h1>
      </a></li>
    <!-- endLogotype -->
    <li><a href="#">Text Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font: 81.25% Arial;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em 0.4em;
}
.nav li a h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.logo img {
    height: 1em;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeBi/8Bmqt/32/)

I've updated the example with reworked code with a shortened version of the [jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/MeBi/8Bmqt/32/). (Make some horizontal room to view the result) to better illustrate the objective how I want the graphic to behave. 
In the fiddle the graphic is just a screen dump of the text cut to 26 pixels height and set to the height of 2em. The root em is then typically 13px.

In the example you can see that the graphic actually is resizing in Firefox, which is hopeful. However an image isn't text so some adjustments have to be made to make the graphic sit at the same spot and behave like the sibling text links.

In the real world the graphic isn't the same size and look and would need some offsets to sit right with the text. But when resizing the page the graphic would **resize like the text**.

Comment: Alwasy use PX insteed of em because em is interpreted different by some latest browsers. .logo img { height:30px; }

Comment: Well, using px will not resize the image also when user is zooming only text, will it?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been upfront about that requirement. My apologies.
If you have any leads on what browsers interpret ems differently I'd be most interested to hear about this. Thanks for your response. Ideas always get my mind going even if I don't understand them right away.

Comment: What does the resizing problem look like on Safari, and on which platform? Can you post minimal code that demonstrates the issue? (Safari 5.1.7 on Windows seems to resize an image properly when height is specified in `em` units, at least in a simple case.)

Comment: I'll try and prepare a jfiddle example for this. I'll post again soon.

Comment: @MiB check my update answer.. also.. here you can find multi browser screenshots to see that picture us same size in all browser...  http://browsershots.org/http://jsfiddle.net/mKt3c/

Comment: I've updated the code above and posted a version at http://jsfiddle.net/MeBi/8Bmqt/32/ (Make som horizontal room to view the result)

I'm looking at micadellis solution too and other suggestions. I just freed up some time to solve this, so will work on this tomorrow thursday. Thank you for all your responses. I find them interesting and stimulating.

Answer (score 0):

you could resize your images with this piece of code:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

... or if you would like to have a maximum size for the image, put it into the container, as follows (keeping the img declaration above):

```
.container {
    max-width: 300px;
}
<div class="container">
    <img src="logo_115x39.png">
</div>
```

This could *easily* be modified so that your container's max-width equals the wanted height in ems.

**Update:**
If I understood your question correctly you could set your pictures max-width, instead of height by calculating the aspect ratio of the image. The calculation below is made with 5.46em you mentioned in your question. See JSFiddle demo and scale the window smaller to see the picture shrink.

```
.logo div {
    /* 
    115px / 39px = 2.948717948717949
    2.948717948717949 x 5.46em = 16.1em
    */
    max-width: 16.1em;
}
.logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 hack */
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/mKt3c/

Comment: How does this relate to the question about sizing in `em` units?

Comment: Well, @JukkaK.Korpela I was thinking the same thing. I clarified the objective above as "to have the image resize in the exact same amount as the text does". 
To achieve this maybe I need to climb out of my preconception to solve this with ems, even if an em solution would have been nice and tidy.

Comment: @micadelli, I'll contemplate your idea which is nevertheless interesting to research and see if that would solve anything. It might work if I recut the image. 

What seems against using percentages is of course that provided there is a (older) browser that don't support downloadable fonts — I use Google fonts — then the next font in the stack will be used and its sizes will change everything.
Possibly then also the fonts could be set with percentages to match the image. I guess I have to make some new tests and find out some more. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: @MiB I'll update my answer soon, to include a better example with ems.

Comment: @micadelli, I must apologize for not posting a more to the point example initially. I forked your jsfiddle and posted a [version](http://jsfiddle.net/MeBi/8Bmqt/32/) perhaps better illustrating the objective. I'll look into this again tomorrow (3 am here).